# Compilation error for SQL_MACRO in oracle 19C

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, sql-macro

```
create or replace function f_get_ids(p_user in nvarchar2)
return nvarchar2 sql_macro(table)
as
begin
  return q'[select id from table1 where user=p_user]';
end;
```

while executing the above code in oracle 19.0.0.0.0 version getting the below error.

Error(1,27): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     ; is default authid as cluster order using external    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate    result_cache accessible rewrite

Comment: I think you need at least 19.7 to be able to use SQL macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix once you get to the right patch level on 19c.

Because there is only ONE type of macro in 19c, you don't need to quantify which type, eg

```
SQL> create or replace function f_get_ids(p_user in nvarchar2)
  2  return nvarchar2 sql_macro(table)
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    return q'[select id from table1 where user=p_user]';
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create or replace function f_get_ids(p_user in nvarchar2)
  2  return nvarchar2 sql_macro     
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    return q'[select id from table1 where user=p_user]';
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.
```

Same as when you asked here as well  :-)

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=error-while-executing-sql-macro-in-19c